# How to set up Tesseract OCR in Java?

Tags: java, api, ocr, tesseract

I am working on a pretty simple Java project in Visual Studio Code which requires the use of some basic optical character recognition, but I don't have any real experience in setting up APIs or accessing third party software in my code. I'm using Maven to access a Tesseract package from Sourceforge and I got access to a Tesseract class (API?) which takes in a file path (which I believe is used to access the C++ side of things). I used homebrew to install Tesseract and it gave me the file path:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1
```

but when I plug that into this

```
Tesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1");
```

and run the doOCR method it always results in the same Null-Pointer errors, which makes me think that it isn't correctly accessing Tesseract- especially because the same errors will appear regardless of the file path I input. These are the errors...

```
21:25:56.021 [main] ERROR net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.dispose(Tesseract.java:819)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:239)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:194)
        at com.liamross.tess4j.TessClass.main(TessClass.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:245)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:194)
        at com.liamross.tess4j.TessClass.main(TessClass.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.dispose(Tesseract.java:819)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:239)
```

I followed [this article](https://linuxhint.com/tess4j_maven_java_tutorial/) as closely as I could, but no matter what I always receive these errors. Also, it seems that there is another directory or library called libtesseract? I'm not quite sure what that's used for or if it's something that I would need...

I know this is a bit of an ambitious project for someone who doesn't have a ton of experience, but any help would be greatly appreciated - I've put a lot of time into trying to figure this out and there doesn't seem to be much comprehensible material about this.
[Here's a screenshot of what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXJWA.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used the tool before, and only did some cursory Internet searches for answers, but try downloading this file and pointing at your local copy of it (assuming you're trying to read English text): https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/eng.traineddata.

Comment: `setDatapath` should be set to `tessdata` folder, which contains `*.traineddata` files.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your project and at the first time, the same error shown. That's because the Tesseract version is not compatible. Here is the solution:

1. Install the [Tesseract4](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/). My machine is Win10-64bit, so i installed `tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v4.0.0.20181030.exe`. Make sure it's installed successfully.
2. **Cleaning the Java Language Server Worspace** in VS Code, then run again.

> Pay attention to the path of `tessdata` and .`jpg` file.

Set `instance.setHocr(false)` to make sure the content was read correctly:

[image]

`instance.setHocr(true)` will show you xml code:

[image]